# DB administration worflow on SQLite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In the web projects I've worked so far I've always had remote db services (like AWS RDS) where test/staging/prod db environments were running.

As an admin and a SQL expert, I've always been used to directly connect to the db via ssh tunnel with key pair and a client like DBeaver or MySQL Workbench in order to make complicated read queries and occasionally get my hands dirty with direct SQL insert/update/delete.

Now, for a side project of mine I would like to start easy using SQLite on a long running NodeJS server.
In this setup, how would one connect directly to the db for read/write sql statements?

I read along some stuff and I get that I can quite easily make "read replicas" of my db on the cloud (e.g. on AWS S3) using [litestream.io](https://litestream.io/) and this could satisfy my SQL reads requirements: I just download the most recent db to my local machine and have fun.

But what about *writing* to my test/staging/production environments?

Apart from building a CRUD web admin panel, I didn't find anything so far.

How do you guys handle this situation?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.